# Post : unsupported protocol scheme ""

Tags: golang

Почему когда я импортирую `string` переменную конфига `"http://sitex.com/"` у меня появляется ошибка `Post : unsupported protocol scheme ""`, а когда я вручную прописываю эту же переменную в качестве аргумента `Handler("http://sitex.com/", 80)` у меня все работает?

Код `yaml.yml:`

```
HOST:
  host: http://sitex.com/
```

Код `main.go:`

```
package main

import "net/http"
import "net/url"
import "bytes"
import "github.com/jinzhu/configor"
import "fmt"

var Config = struct {
    HOST struct {
        Host string `yaml:"host"`
    } `yaml:"HOST"`

}{} 

configor.Load(&Config, "config.yml") */
func Handler(host string, port int) {
  posthandl := url.Values {
    "username" : {"Jack"},
  }

  form := bytes.NewBufferString(posthandl.Encode())
  req, err := http.Post(host, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", form)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    panic(err)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(req.Body)
  }
}

func main() {
  Handler(Config.HOST.Host, 80) // так не работает, а если пропишу первым аргументом http://sitex.com/ то есть Handler("http://sitex.com/", 80) тогда все будет работать.
}
```

Я заменил `https` на `http` но результата не дало.

Comment: убедитесь что `Config.HOST.Host` содержит ваш хост. Ошибка в структуре ``Host string `yaml:"host"` ``. Пропущены ковычки.

Comment: @biosckon добавил, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Распечатайте в main Config.HOST.Host

Comment: @biosckon обновил. Или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: я имел ввиду [вот так](https://play.golang.com/p/TJps0Haamq). ещё вы даёте содержимое `yaml.yml` а в коде читаете `config.yml` убедитесь что вы читаете правильный файл.

Comment: @biosckon спасибо, я совсем невнимательный, я забыл импортировать сам конфиг потому что переписывал код, забыл добавить строку `configor.Load(&Config, "config.yml")`